# How to stop useAsyncState from running immediately?

Tags: vue.js, vueuse

I am trying to use the [useAsyncState()](https://vueuse.org/core/useAsyncState/) from the [VueUse library](https://vueuse.org/).

I am using the `{ immediate: false }` option flag because I do NOT want it to run immediately.

But the code always gets run immediately, and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```TypeScript
import { useAsyncState } from '@vueuse/core';
const firstNameSubmit = useAsyncState(
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Bob');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  }),
  undefined,
  { immediate: false }
);

const handleFirstNameSubmit = () => {
  firstNameSubmit.execute();
};
```

And here is a reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ylzoyt/?file=src%2FApp.vue

I also tried doing the opposite and using `{ immediate: true }`, along with excluding the options object altogether, but none of those solutions work.

The promise inside `useAsyncState` always runs immediately.

Comment: It's simple and works unambiguously https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/useAsyncState/index.ts#L122 . Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem

Comment: I just updated the question with a new example and a reproduction.

Comment: This is the reason why it accepts a function instead of a promise. There's no way how it could postpone a promise that has been already created. This becomes evident when the example uses `new Promise` instead of functions that aren't shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a promise is created, it cannot be postponed. In order to avoid this, it should be wrapped with a function that can be explicitly called.

It should be:

```
const firstNameSubmit = useAsyncState(
  () => ...,
  undefined,
  { immediate: false }
);

...

firstNameSubmit.execute();
```

Comment: Sorry but I still don't undertstand, isn't that what I have done by using `handleFirstNameSubmit`? Do you mind forking the example reproduction and changing it to show how it can be triggered when clicking the button?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-cs3vkr/ You don't have `() => ...` part in the op. It's not about triggering `execute`, it's about how `useAsyncState` is called. The explanation of the problem is `var promise =  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Bob');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  })`. Then try to not make it not call `console.log` by doing something with `promise` var. You won't be able to do that. Same here.

Comment: Ok thanks I get it now :)